# Trying to get the initials of 2 string in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
initt [f:_] [l:_] = f ++ " " ++ l
```

And then i call

```
initt "First" "Last"
```

I get an error, saying Couldn't match type 'Char' with '[Char]'

I really don't get it.

Comment: It must be `[f, ' ', l]`

Answer (score 9):

I think you want

```
initt (f:_) (l:_) = [f, ' ', l]
```

`[f:_]` is equivalent to `[(f:_)]` which would match something like `["First"]`

Also `(++)` works on strings, while `f` & `l` are supposed to be chars. At best, you could do something like `[c] ++ " " ++ [l]` but `[f, ' ', 'l']` is much better & simpler.

Comment: " [f:_] is equivalent to [(f:_)] " - why?

Comment: In general, patterns like `[a, b, c]` will match lists with the specified length, in this case 3. `[a]` matches a list with one element. If you use a pattern like `[(f:_)]` you're matching a list with one element, which is itself a list with its head bound to `f`. However, in this case, Haskell lets you drop the parenthesis so you can write `[f:_]`.

Answer (score 4):

`++` is *list* concatenation. Either pack `f` and `l` into lists:

```
[f] ++ " " ++ [l]
```

Or create it like Ingo suggested:

```
[f, ' ', l]
```

Also, pattern matching on `head:tail` implies it's a list, so instead of `[f:_]`, you need simply `(f:_)`.

Which brings us to the whole solution:

```
initt (f:_) (l:_) = [f, ' ', l]
```